# Nested Hover css with span

Tags: css

Please refer to https://jsfiddle.net/gmczjrmp/1/ for easier understanding.

In **First Table** everything works fine. In fact, this is what I need in **Second table** as well, which is a nested table.

When hovered over, only a single row should highlight, as in the **First table**

I tried changing

```
tr:hover span.hover2show
```

to

```
tr:hover > span.hover2show
```

but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: span is not the direct child of tr there is a td in between try: `tr:hover > td > span.hover2show`

Comment: `tr:hover > span.hover2show` would never work. `>` indicates that `span` is a direct child of `tr` but isn't since you have a `td` between the `span` and the `tr`. Even if you used malformed HTML without `td`s the browser would likely automatically insert the `td`s.

Comment: Please add code to the question - links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

Make things easier and give your tables that have this functionality a class, that way you can more easily distinguish them in your code and select them in your css:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 4px;
}

table.hoverable tr:hover span.hover2show {
  visibility: visible;
  color:red;
}

span {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
First Table
<table class='hoverable'>
  <tr>
    <td> r1c1 </td>
    <td> r1c2 </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r1c3  </span> </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r1c4  </span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> r2c1 </td>
    <td> r2c2 </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r2c3  </span> </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r2c4  </span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> r3c1 </td>
    <td> r3c2 </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r3c3  </span> </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r3c4  </span> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
Second Table
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Outer table
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class='hoverable'>
        <tr>
          <td> r1c1 </td>
          <td> r1c2 </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r1c3  </span> </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r1c4  </span> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> r2c1 </td>
          <td> r2c2 </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r2c3  </span> </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r2c4  </span> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> r3c1 </td>
          <td> r3c2 </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r3c3  </span> </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r3c4  </span> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      Outer table
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try giving individual classes. please have a look in code pane alos

HTML

```
First Table
<table class="first-table">
  <tr>
    <td> r1c1 </td>
    <td> r1c2 </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r1c3  </span> </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r1c4  </span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> r2c1 </td>
    <td> r2c2 </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r2c3  </span> </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r2c4  </span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> r3c1 </td>
    <td> r3c2 </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r3c3  </span> </td>
    <td> <span class="hover2show">    r3c4  </span> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
Second Table
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Outer table
    </td>
    <td>
      <table class="second-table">
        <tr>
          <td> r1c1 </td>
          <td> r1c2 </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r1c3  </span> </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r1c4  </span> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> r2c1 </td>
          <td> r2c2 </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r2c3  </span> </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r2c4  </span> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> r3c1 </td>
          <td> r3c2 </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r3c3  </span> </td>
          <td> <span class="hover2show">    r3c4  </span> </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      Outer table
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 4px;
}

.first-table tr:hover span.hover2show {
  visibility: visible;
  color:red;
}


 table .second-table tr:hover span.hover2show {
  visibility: visible;
  color:green;
}
```

Codpen link

http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/NRAApg